# Is there a relation between the mutual coherence and largest eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, spectral-norm

Let $A=[a_1,\dots,a_n]\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$ be a matrix with columns $a_1,\dots,a_n$ having unit norm, i.e., $\|a_i\|=1$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$. Let

$$ L := \lambda_{\max} \left( A^T A \right) $$

and

$$\gamma := \max_{i\neq j} \,\, |\langle a_i, a_j\rangle|$$ be the largest correlation of columns of $A$. In other words, $\gamma$ is the largest (in absolute value) off-diagonal entry of $A^TA$ and is known as the [mutual coherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_coherence_(linear_algebra)) of $A$. It is easy to see that $\gamma\leq 1$.

I observe numerically the following fact when $\gamma$ is close to $1$, then $L$ tends to infinity. Is this a basic fact? If not, how can I formalize this idea?

---

**Motivation.** This fact happens in the [ISTA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sy4pRJ3g530) algorithm, a solving method for Lasso problem. In this algorithm, if the matrix $A$ has large coherence $\gamma$, then the convergence of ISTA method is very slow since its step size $1/L$ is very small. So I think that we should have a relation between $\gamma$ and $L$.

Comment: $\big \Vert A\big \Vert_F^2 = n\implies L\leq n$ with equality *iff* $A$ is rank one

Comment: @user8675309 wao. But is there a lower bound for $L$? Since we want to show that $L$ tends to infinity.

Comment: Isn't $L$ the squared spectral norm of $A$?

Comment: The title is misleading.  The MC of $A$ but the largest eigenvalue of $A^T A$. Different matrices.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I am not sure. But I know that $L$ is the square of the largest singular value.

Comment: Then why not take the SQRT and use the largest singular value?

Comment: yes, you are totally right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A^TA$ is a symmetric $n\times n$ real matrix, there exists an orthonormal basis $v_1,\dots,v_n$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ of eigenvectors of $A^TA$. Let $\lambda_k$ denote the eigenvalue corresponding to the eigenvector $v_k$. The eigenvalue Since for each $1\leq k\leq n$ we have
$$\|Av_k\|^2=\langle A^TAv_k,v_k\rangle = \lambda_k$$
so that the eigenvalues are nonnegative, and their sum equals the trace of the matrix $A^TA$,
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_k=\sum_{k=1}^n\langle A^TAv_k,v_k\rangle=\hbox{Tr}(A^TA)=\sum_{i=1}^n\langle A^TAe_k,e_k\rangle$$
where $e_k$ is the standard basis. Here the fact that the trace of a matrix can be evaluated via any orthonormal basis was used.
It follows that we can bound the sum of the eigenvalues, and therefore also the maximal eigenvalue, by a function of the diagonal elements of the matrix $A^TA$. In particular, it is impossible to cause the maximal eigenvalue to grow indefinitely just by altering the off-diagonal elements.  This argument on its own does not yet provide a quantitative connection between the maximal eigenvector and the maximal off-diagonal elements, but it does hint to the fact that the diagonal of the matrix carries much of the information pertinent to the size of the eigenvalues.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I see the point! just a very small remark $\text{Tr} (A^TA)=n$.